# Replace string content with arbitrary number of four characters in middle of string?

Tags: regex, r, string, text, stringr

Goal: turn x into y; where x has an arbitrary number of spaces, \rs, and \ns.

```
x <- "some text,                    \r\n                    \r\n)more text"
y <- "some text)more text"
```

I've made a few attempts using str_replace_all():

```
str_replace_all(x, "[,][ \r\n][)]", "")
str_replace_all(x, ",[ \r\n])", "")
```

Comment: Arbitrary number of characters ? Do you mean `[add chars here]+` ? Or, like `,[ \r\n]*(?=\))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` will do this job for you.

```
gsub(",\\s*\\n\\s*\\)", ")", s)
```

or

```
gsub(",\\s*[\\r\\n]+\\s*\\)", ")", s)
```

**Example:**

```
> x <- "some text,                    \r\n                    \r\n)more text"
> gsub(",\\s*\\n\\s*\\)", ")", x)
[1] "some text)more text"
```